# is it possible to process html to auto close tags with no close tags?

Tags: c#, html

i have this string

```
<div>
  <p><strong>Elem_A</strong>String_A2_2 <String_A2_2> asdas</p>
  <p><strong>Elem_B</strong>String_B2_2 String_B2_2</p>
</div>
```

and i want to covert it to

```
<div>
  <p><strong>Elem_A</strong>String_A2_2 <String_A2_2/> asdas</p>
  <p><strong>Elem_B</strong>String_B2_2 String_B2_2</p>
</div>
```

basically i want to autoclose any non html known tag , because i have problems with processing this html in htmlagilitypack as it changes the meaning of the html.

Comment: Could you explain the larger process/goal? I'd be asking why you have that tag in your HTML that you're parsing.

Comment: i am parsing html malformed html files , that is why i have this tag in my html.
i am using htmlagilitypack to parse the html further but the problem is that htmlagilitypack autocloses the tags incorectly and so it ends up modifying my html, this is why i want to pre process it before giving the html to htmlagilitypack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML (meaning not XHTML) already does this: [auto closed tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) are defined without a trailing closing `/` (`<br>`).

I'm not familiar with `htmlagilitypack`, but if you make your own DTD based on HTML4.01, extended with your own tag, then there must be some HTML parser that can work.

---

Also, just curious, why are you using "special" tags within HTML?

Comment: I think he meant XHTML, not HTML and doesn't care about entities that are valid in HTML/XHTML but entities that don't exist (such as <String_A2_2> -> <String_A2_2 />

Comment: @Tegeril: a custom DTD might help him if the parser relies on it to parse.

Comment: i want to do this programaticaly using some parser [c#]

Comment: i am not using special tags, but this special tags are basically unescapped text that was generated by error into the html